# Activity with ViewPager does not scroll vertically

Tags: android, android-viewpager, scrollview, android-tabs

I have this Activity with a Toolbar and an image below the Toolbar with few TextViews below that. I have implemented Tabs below that. The horizontal scroll for Tabs work fine. When the content in a Tab is more the vertical ScrollView works fine inside the VieewPager section. But I want to make the whole page Scoll vertically when the content of the tabs are more. I have tried to customize the ScrollView class.  I do not want to collapse the content in the Toolbar. I jst want to scroll the whole page. But nothing worked. Please help me guys !! Thanks in advance.[image]

This is my XML code -

```
    <RelativeLayout

android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#FFFFFF">



<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar">

<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/md_grey_200"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relative_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/gradient">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="120dp"
                android:id="@+id/imageLayout"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:background="@drawable/image_background">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/courseimage"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:background="@drawable/sq_default"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>

            </RelativeLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:background="#FFFFFF"
                android:layout_above="@+id/card_view8"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageLayout"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/card_view8"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/card_view8"
                android:id="@+id/linearLayout11"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:background="#FFFFFF"
                android:layout_above="@+id/card_view8"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageLayout"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/card_view8"
                android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/card_view8"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

            </LinearLayout>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/card_view8"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                card_view:cardBackgroundColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/imageLayout"
                card_view:cardCornerRadius="0dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/coursetitle"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:paddingTop="8dp"
                        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
                        android:text=""
                        android:textColor="#58595b"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:textSize="17sp"
                        android:maxLines="2"
                        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/institutetitle"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:paddingTop="4dp"
                        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
                        android:text=""
                        android:textColor="#58595b"
                        android:maxLines="2"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:textSize="14sp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/batch_detail"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:paddingTop="4dp"
                        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
                        android:text=""
                        android:textColor="#58595b"
                        android:maxLines="2"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:textSize="14sp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/button_enroll"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:textSize="15sp"
                        android:paddingRight="28dp"
                        android:paddingLeft="28dp"
                        android:paddingTop="12dp"
                        android:paddingBottom="12dp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                        android:background="@drawable/red_button"
                        android:text=""
                        android:layout_below="@+id/coursetitle"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"/>

                </LinearLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        </RelativeLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@color/md_grey_300" />

           <LinearLayout
               android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:weightSum="3"
               android:background="#FFFFFF">

               <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tabs"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:tabMode="scrollable"
                    app:tabGravity="fill"
                    app:tabTextColor="@color/md_grey_700"
                    app:tabSelectedTextColor="#fd4347"
                    app:tabIndicatorColor="#fd4347"
                    app:tabIndicatorHeight="2dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>

         </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@color/md_grey_300" />

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/viewpager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1">

            </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

</LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: It is difficult to understand exactly what you are trying to do. Are you trying to collapse the content between the toolbar and tabs as the user scrolls up? In any case, post some code. Your xml and any other relevant code would help.

Comment: Thanks Bryan I just added. No I do not want to collapse the content in the toolbar. I jst want to scroll the whole page.

Comment: What does the layout for the fragments inside your `ViewPager` look like? Do those fragments have a separate `ScrollView`?

Answer (score 1):

Try a `CoordinatorLayout` with a `NestedScrollView` (and make sure you apply the `app:layout_behavior`):

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content>

            <!-- The rest of your layout content here -->

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```